# call stopVideoCapture method in Background thread - iOS

Tags: ios, ios5

i'm making video capture function with overlay view. And now i want to call stopVideoCapture method in UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification. but the "stopVideoCapture" method is always failed with error message “/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/takingvideo activity indicator already cleared”.

please tell me what's the problem.

following is the code invoked in UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

self.bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
    self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    if (isRecording) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self.imagePickerController stopVideoCapture];             
        });
    }

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];

    [app endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
    self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
```